# Terraform azure databricks unity catalog from start

Tags: azure, terraform, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I would like to create a single terraform .tf that creates my databricks environment from scratch. I have followed an example that creates an databricks workspace in azure and it works fine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/terraform/azure-workspace

Seems like this also creates components needed for unity catalog like Managed identity, access connector and storage account. But unity catalog is not enabled. In the code example, this is the part that actually makes the resource:

```
resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "this" {
  name                        = "${local.prefix}-workspace"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.this.location
  sku                         = "premium"
  managed_resource_group_name = "${local.prefix}-workspace-rg"
  tags                        = local.tags
}
```

What am I missing to be able to get the Unity catalog enabled through terraform?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is the enable option in the documentation? ... that resource you show does not show anything about "catalog" in the documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/databricks_workspace

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/guides/unity-catalog-azure#deploying-pre-requisite-resources-and-enabling-unity-catalog

Comment: Strange thing is that when I created the workspace as shown above, it automaticly created managed Identity, storage account and access connector, but i dont see any option how I can Get this enabled through the terraform code. Found something about this in the terraform documentation, but this is when unikt catalog components is created automaticly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I missing to be able to get the Unity catalog enabled through terraform?

Here is the updated terraform code to create a `meta store` and enabled **Unity catalog**.

```kotlin
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
        }
        databricks = {
          source = "databricks/databricks"
        }
      }
    }
    
    provider "azurerm" {
      subscription_id = ""
      features {}
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rgname" {
      name = "databricks-temp-1"
      location  = "centralus"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "example" {
      name                = "databricks-test"
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.name
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.location
      sku                 = "premium"
    }
     
    provider "databricks" {
      host = azurerm_databricks_workspace.example.workspace_url
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_databricks_access_connector" "unity" {
      name                = "venkatdatabricksmi1"
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.name
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.location
      identity {
        type = "SystemAssigned"
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_storage_account" "unity_catalog" {
      name                     = "thejadatabricksdemo2"
      resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.name
      location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.location
      account_tier             = "Standard"
      account_replication_type = "GRS"
      is_hns_enabled           = true
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_storage_container" "unity_catalog" {
      name                  = "venkat-container2"
      storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.unity_catalog.name
      container_access_type = "private"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
      scope                = azurerm_storage_account.unity_catalog.id
      role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
      principal_id         = azurerm_databricks_access_connector.unity.identity[0].principal_id
    }
    
    resource "databricks_metastore" "this" {
      name     = "demometastoretest"
      storage_root = format("abfss://%s@%s.dfs.core.windows.net/",
        azurerm_storage_container.unity_catalog.name,
        azurerm_storage_account.unity_catalog.name)
      force_destroy = true
      region        = "centralus"
    }
    
    resource "databricks_metastore_assignment" "this" {
      provider             = databricks
      workspace_id         = azurerm_databricks_workspace.example.workspace_id
      metastore_id         = databricks_metastore.this.id
      default_catalog_name = "hive_metastore"
    }
    
    resource "databricks_metastore_data_access" "this" {
      metastore_id = databricks_metastore.this.id
      name         = "mi_dac"
      azure_managed_identity {
        access_connector_id = azurerm_databricks_access_connector.unity.id
      }
      is_default = true
     depends_on = [ databricks_metastore_assignment.this ]
    }
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

After running the code, the `Unity catalog` has been **enabled**.

[image]

The `Databricks workspace` was also successfully added to the **metastore**.

[image]

Reference:  [databricks_metastore Resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/metastore)

[databricks_metastore_data_access (Resource)](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/1.30.0/docs/resources/metastore_data_access#access_connector_id)

Comment: Thanks was much clearer. But I got this issue using the code " cannot create metastore: User is not an account admin for Account.", and i had to enter account console to make the service principal I am using an account admin. Is that possible to do in code?

Comment: For creating a metastore, you need an account admin role, or if you have **owner ** access, the same role will be assigned automatically. Please refer the [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/service-principals#--manage-service-principals-in-your-account)  for more details.